# Dua when looking at the mirror: Is it present in Sahih Hadith books?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

Whenever he looked at the mirror, Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) is narrated to have made this dua ([for example](https://www.searchtruth.com/dua/index.php?dua=36)):

> O Allah, just as You have made my external features beautiful, make my
>   character beautiful as well.

Is this dua present in sahih hadith books?

(And does it include (may not be accurate): “And please Allah, do not make it a source of Fire.” [Either because I am pleased with it too much, or not pleased with it.])

Comment: اللَّهُمَّ أَنْتَ حَسَّنْتَ خَلْقِي فَحَسِّنْ خُلُقِي

Answer (score 3):

The dua itself is authentic, however narrations that attach it to looking in a mirror are weak.

The dua has been recorded in various collections like *Musnad Ahmad* ([3823](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33037/1727#p1) , [24392](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/20608#p1) , [25221](https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/21305#p1)) where the commentators have classed it as Sahih. It has also been recorded in *Sahih Ibn Hibban* ([959](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/1413)). Al-Albani has graded it as saheeh in *Irwa al-Ghalil* ([74](https://al-maktaba.org/book/22592/127)) and *Sahih al-Jaami as-Sagheer* ([1307](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10757/218)).

**References:**

[islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/ar/239755), [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/92994)

Comment: I don't know Arabic. Does the hadith include what I asked in my post?

Comment: The wording is اللهم أحسنت خلقي فأحسن خلقي , which is the part you have put in the yellow quotation. The latter part is not included, and there is no specification of a mirror in the sahih hadith, though these are present in the weak versions.